# Rails 4 patch request does not update attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, patch, update-attributes

Very new to rails. I'm building a simple app to take a group of users and randomly assign teams of 5. Everything is working fine except for a "Clear Teams" link in one of my views. The links is supposed to update the team and team2 attributes of each user to be 0. When I click the link, the update doesn't happen, and each user's team and team2 attribute remain unchanged.

Model:

```
  def self.clear_teams
    pt = User.all
    pt.each do |v|
      if v.team != 0
        v.update_attribute(:team, 0)
      end
      if v.team2 != 0
        v.update_attribute(:team2, 0)
      end
    end
  end
```

Calling User.clear_teams in the console works, so I'm thinking I have a routing issue.

Controller:

```
  def clear
    @users = User.all
    @users.clear_teams
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

View:

```
    <%= link_to "Clear Teams", clear_users_path, method: :patch, class: 'col-xs-12 btn-primary clear', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to clear the teams?' } %>
```

routes.rb:

```
patch 'users' => 'users#clear', as: :clear_users
```

Routes:

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)     users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)     users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format) users#new
       user DELETE /users/:id(.:format) users#destroy
            DELETE /users(.:format)     users#destroy_all
            PATCH  /users(.:format)     users#randomize
clear_users PATCH  /users(.:format)     users#clear
       root GET    /                    users#index
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a class method `clear_teams`. You need to be calling it like `User.clear_teams`, not like an instance method - which is what you currently have in your `clear` action. See article on difference @ http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/